# Untable a dataframe that has been aggregated

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, reshape2

I have the following data frame in R:

```
Name    Year     Apples   Bananas    
Tom     2012        3       4
John    2012        0       1
John    2013        3       2
John    2014        5       3
Alexa   2012        2       2
Alexa   2013        2       1
```

I would like to transform or reshape the dataframe, to have the frequency of apples and bananas per person represented in the dataframe. Like this: It would ideal to use dplyr or reshape packages

```
Name   Year.    Fruit
Tom    2012     Apples
Tom    2012     Apples
Tom    2012     Apples
Tom    2012     Bananas
Tom    2012     Bananas
Tom    2012     Bananas
John   2012     Bananas
John   2013     Apples
John   2013     Apples
John   2013     Apples
John   2013     Bananas
John   2013     Bananas
John   2014     Apples
John   2014     Apples
John   2014     Apples
John   2014     Apples
John   2014     Apples
John   2014     Bananas
John   2014     Bananas
John   2014     Bananas
```

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library( data.table )

#sample data
# mydata <- fread( "Name    Year     Apples   Bananas
# Tom     2012        3       4
# John    2012        0       1
# John    2013        3       2
# John    2014        5       3
# Alexa   2012        2       2
# Alexa   2013        2       1   ")

ans <- melt( setDT( mydata ), id.vars = c("Name","Year"), variable.name = "Fruit" )
ans[ rep(seq(.N), value), !"value"]
```

*output*

```
#      Name Year   Fruit
#  1:   Tom 2012  Apples
#  2:   Tom 2012  Apples
#  3:   Tom 2012  Apples
#  4:  John 2013  Apples
#  5:  John 2013  Apples
#  6:  John 2013  Apples
#  7:  John 2014  Apples
#  8:  John 2014  Apples
#  9:  John 2014  Apples
# 10:  John 2014  Apples
# 11:  John 2014  Apples
# 12: Alexa 2012  Apples
# 13: Alexa 2012  Apples
# 14: Alexa 2013  Apples
# 15: Alexa 2013  Apples
# 16:   Tom 2012 Bananas
# 17:   Tom 2012 Bananas
# 18:   Tom 2012 Bananas
# 19:   Tom 2012 Bananas
# 20:  John 2012 Bananas
# 21:  John 2013 Bananas
# 22:  John 2013 Bananas
# 23:  John 2014 Bananas
# 24:  John 2014 Bananas
# 25:  John 2014 Bananas
# 26: Alexa 2012 Bananas
# 27: Alexa 2012 Bananas
# 28: Alexa 2013 Bananas
#      Name Year   Fruit
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is almost it. There is one error though for the final part. I get this:


Error in !"value" : invalid argument type

Comment: I used this and it worked: ans.expanded <- ans[rep(row.names(ans), ans$value), 1:6]